# Wifi too much “Invalid misc”, how to fix it?

Tags: debian, error-handling, wlan

Here are some outputs:

```
root@debian:/home/love# iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"SITI_Broadband-06E6-G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: FC:4A:E9:4B:06:E8   
          Bit Rate=15 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:202   Missed beacon:0
```

I noticed the value increases with time and my wifi stay connected but internet stop working.

Comment: That looks like a typical wifi interference problem.  Try to locate the device causing the issue and when you do, delete this question as it would be off-topic.  Simply turning most electronic equipment off and paying attention to what changes when the problems start can usually solve 90% of these.

Comment: I have netgear external wifi adaptor, It worked fine with windows but when I had Debian it had similar problem, Now I installed kali linux (and it doesn't require me to install its drivers) It has same problem.

Comment: Can you still try it on Windows to see if the situation may have changed?

Comment: My situation sees over 1M invalid packets. Yes, it's that noisy here, and I can't switch to 5G.

Comment: I'm seeing this with my Intel 8260 adapter. What is frustrating is that all I can see is this high-level error count. How can I see the actual errors that my adapter is emitting in a log?